# Compile and hide AngularJs template in the page source

Tags: angularjs

My question is how do I hide the template tags when using AngularJs. What I mean is in index.html I have this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myApp">
    <head data-ng-controller="CtrlHead">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{{title}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>             
        <div data-ng-view></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I look at that page in the browser, then right click > view source, I can see all of that code and see exactly how the page was constructed.

Is there some way to compile the AngularJs template and only show the finished html (with {{title}} added and the actual view instead of data-ng-view) in the view source?

Please note I am not talking about [ngCloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angCloak) which prevents the {{tag}} from being flashed before the template is compiled.

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What value does it add?

Comment: The main reason was that the client requested it. His reasoning was that he just wanted to hide as much of what we were doing as possible and we use some elaborate templates that he didn't want "them" to "steal" :) BTW this was a while ago and I convinced him not to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no simple Angular magic for this. You will need to have your server serve up html snapshots. This won't work for what you're serving to actual people, as there will be no javascript involved. It's just a dump of a page's completed output after javascript runs.

You can use a headless browser like [**PhantomJS**](http://phantomjs.org/) running on your server to "visit" your pages on a schedule, capture the compiled html, save the html to files and then serve those files for SEO crawlers.

What I do is a little nicer for my situation. I built a Content Management System, so all changes to the site are managed through that. Anytime a change is made, the site is loaded inside the admin panel itself (iframe) and I capture the output from there and save the snapshot.

To tell crawlers that a page is ajax based and to look elsewhere for a snapshot, put this in the head of the document: `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` which tells google to look for `www.example.com` at `www.example.com?_escaped_fragment_=`. You would then setup your server to serve the snapshot of the homepage for that request.
Info from google here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

There's also this service that can do this for you: https://ajaxsnapshots.com